# How to fix nginx 404 not found for a Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

All my routes got `404` Not Found. I can open Laravel page if I access the `localhost/mylaravel`, but if I access `localhost/mylaravel/login`, I got 404 not found page. If I change route home on /home and access it, I got 404 not found.

I'm using Laravel Framework 5.6.33

This is my routes file:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home/home');
});
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login/login');
});
```

And this is my nginx config at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location /mylaravel/ {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; 
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|txt|ico|swf|xml|woff|woff2|ttf|mp3|svg|csv|xls|xlsx|eot|otf)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires modified +90d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Who is throwing 404? nginx or laravel? Take into consideration that nginx root should point to the `public/` dir, would be like so: `root /var/www/html/public/;` **if** it happens to be true that your app dir lives there. Finally, it looks like you have 2 app instances configured in the same serverblock, you may refactor that into 2 different serverblocks and avoid a lot of hassle.

Comment: @alariva nginx is throwing 404 not found page

Comment: What about pointing to public ? Can you post an `ls -l /var/www/html/` ?

Comment: I already pointed to public. there are 2 directories. mylaravel and mylaravel-html

Comment: What about the `ls` output, can you share it?

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 12 tux  tux  4096 Agu 14 14:16 mylaravel
drwxrwxr-x 13 tux  tux  4096 Agu 16 10:31 mylaravel-html

Comment: Please check out this serverblock, replace yours (make a backup), set the correct domain name (use `local.mylaravel` if you are on local), remember to set DNS or hostfile accordingly and restart nginx. https://pastebin.com/A6TavDXH

Comment: Do you have 2 applications? one in `mylaravel` and another in `mylaravel-html`?

Comment: no, I just have mylaravel and mylaravel-html. mylaravel-html just html for mylaravel. I'm using localhost.

Comment: Then try editing the file I sent over pastebin and return back results. You will probably need to add a line to `/etc/hosts` to alias a local host for testing purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

The following line:

```
root /var/www/html/;
```

should be

```
root /var/www/html/public;
```

Your webroot should be set to the public directory within the Laravel project, because that is the entry point of the framework