# Nginx 404 Not Found Error. How can I fix it?

Tags: laravel, nginx, server, http-status-code-404

**I'm using Laravel 8 for my project.**

**Php: 7.4**

**Using AWS Nginx Server**

My Application's Homepage is fine. The homepage is working well. But, when I'm clicking a link then I'm getting a 404 Not Found error from **Nginx**.

Here is my server config in `nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name something.com;
    root /srv/something.com;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**What to do? What to change?**

**How to fix this error?**

Comment: What link is producing this 404 error?

Comment: @ewong when I am clicking `/about` page, it's producing '/about' with Nginx 404 error

Comment: I've installed new laravel application. But, I got same problame. Here is my `web.php` `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/about', function () {
   echo "about";
});`

Comment: I had the same issue. The below solution worked for me. [how-to-fix-nginx-404-not-found-for-a-laravel-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869231/how-to-fix-nginx-404-not-found-for-a-laravel-app)

Comment: @Jerry, I do not have `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` directory